# Application works in visual studio but release/debug exe does not

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directx-11, directsound

I am making a game using `dx11`. When I compile and run the code in visual studio it works fine however if I try and run the code from the .exe file in either the debug or release folders I got the following error:

```
"Could not initialize direct sound"
```

I have not moved the folders/directories at all.

Is this something to do with direct sound not being compatible with `dx11`? If so why would it still run inside visual studio.

I am using MS Visual Studio 10. My direct sound class has the following:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dsound.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <dsound.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Advance Thanks

Comment: Is this a custom error you've set? If so, check the area which throws the error. My best bet is that you've got some resources (such as sound files) missing that you initialization code relies on.

If I recall correctly, VS uses the project root as the start path for the application, where as the Release/Debug exe will use it's current location. Resources will need to be copied into those folders for it to work/

Comment: Can you post some code where this throw/catch is at?

Comment: SlxS was exactly right. I needed to move my resources to the debug and release folders. Thanks guys!